# Fourier transform for $H^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, $N\geq 5$

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform, pseudo-differential-operators

How i can prove that if $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ then $u\in \mathcal{F}(L^{p^*}(\mathbb{R}^N))$, where $1/p+1/{p^*}=1,$ $2\leq p<2N/(N-4)$?

Answer (score 4):

If $u \in H^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, then its Fourier transform satisfies $\hat{u} \in L^2$ and $(1 + |\xi|^2) \hat{u} \in L^2$. By Holder inequality you have

$$  \|\hat{u}\|_{q} \leq \| (1 + |\xi|^2)^{-1} \|_{r} \|(1 + |\xi|^2) \hat{u} \|_{2} $$

for appropriate $q^{-1} = r^{-1} + 2^{-1}$. For the $L^r$ integration to be bounded you need $2r > N$. Work through the algebra you get what you want.

Comment: Sorry, @WillieWong! I dind't understand how  $\hat{u}\in L^q$ implies $u\in \mathcal{F}(L^q)$?

Comment: @Pádua maybe I misunderstood your notation, but I thought you meant by $u\in \mathcal{F}(L^q)$ that $u$ has a Fourier transform that is in $L^q$. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, @WillieWong! I wanted to say that $u=\mathcal{F}(v)$ for some $v \in L^{q}\left(\mathbb{R}^{N}\right)$, $1\leq q\leq 2$.

Comment: @Pádua: then is it not what I just stated? You can easily go from the Fourier transform $\hat{u}$ of the function $u$ to the function $v$ (which is just the inverse Fourier transform of $u$).

Comment: Sorry @WillierWong, but i don't know how go from the Fourier transform  to inverse. There exists some relation between them?

Comment: @Pádua: you just compose with reflection. See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem

Comment: I think I understand @WillieWong. Thank you!